# Вылетает приложение андроид(java), при попытке поиска pdf файлов в папке загрузки

Tags: java, android, listview, pdf, find

пишу приложение под андроид на java, в данный момент пытаюсь сделать следующее: найти все файлы в папке загрузки на смартфоне, отфильтровать их по окончанию .pdf, данные помещаю в List(т.к. нужен динамический массив), далее конвертирую его в стринговый массив, а данные из массива передаю уже в ListView. Конвертация работает исправно, проверял. Ошибка возникает где то на уровне поиска файлов. Ошибок не возникает, просто при попытке вызова функции findFiles приложение закрывается. Возможно где то возникают какие то исключения, опыта разработки на java у меня слишком мало.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SA_2 extends AppCompatActivity {
public    String dir = "storage/emulated/0/Download/";
public    String ext = ".pdf";

private ListView list;
private static String [] files2 = new String[] {};
public static   List<String> files1 = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sa_2);
        findFiles(dir, ext);
         list1();
}


public void list1() {

    String[] files = new String[files1.size()];
            files1.toArray(files);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.paths, files);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(
           new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String val = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(i);
               }
            }
    );
}


////////////////////////////////////////////ОШИБКА ГДЕ ТО ТУТ     ///////////////////////////////////////////////


public static void findFiles(String dir, String ext) {

File file = new File(dir);
if(!file.exists())files1.add(dir + " папка не существует");
File[] listFiles =  file.listFiles(new MyFileNameFilter(ext));
if(listFiles.length == 0){
   files1.add(dir + " не содержит файлов с расширением " + ext);
  }
  else
     // {
     for(File f : listFiles)
         files1.add(f.getName());

//}
}
 public static   class MyFileNameFilter implements FilenameFilter{

    private String ext ;

    private MyFileNameFilter(String ext){
        this.ext = ext.toLowerCase();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext);
    }
}



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос на доступ к файловой системе получаете?

В AndroidManifest нужно добавить

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

И в коде перед началом работы с файловой системой

```
 public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нет, не получаю. То, что вы отправили, позволит мне получить доступ?

Comment: Да, но эта реализация не единственная. Можете почитать еще здесь https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Спасибо огромное, добавил нужную строку на запись в манифест, и все заработало

Comment: Пометьте ответ как правильный, чтобы закрыть вопрос